# grep multiple exclude extension

Tags: unix, grep, exclude

I find single exclude extension like

```
grep --exclude "*.js" "a" *
```

How do I write multiple exclude masks?

I have tried the code below, but it doesn't work:

```
grep -r --exclude=*.\{html,htm,js} "li" *

grep -R -E '(\.js|rb)' "create" *
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should escape the asterisk, not the curly brace. Your command should look like this:

```
grep -r --exclude=\*.{html,htm,js} "li" *
```

Answer (score 2):

**man grep** *scroll scroll scroll*

```
 --exclude=GLOB
          Skip files whose base name matches GLOB (using wildcard  matching).
          A  file-name  glob  can use *, ?, and [...]  as wildcards, and \ to
          quote a wildcard or backslash character literally.
```

Look up "shell globbing" for more info

Example:

```
$ grep -r  --exclude=\*.{png,jpg} a .
./moo.txt:a
./moo.htm:a
./hai:a

$ ls
hai  hai.png  moo.htm  moo.txt
```

[Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/221921/grep-exclude-include-syntax-do-not-grep-through-certain-files)

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for exact same thing, but I want to use -v instead, I found the solution [here](https://ioflood.com/blog/grep-exclude-how-to-use-v-to-exclude-words-patterns-or-files-in-grep/)

```
grep -v -e html -e htm -e js
```